# count(*) returning negative value

Tags: mysql

I have a strange problem and something that I haven't come across before.  I have a mysql query like the one below

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total_count FROM postcodes WHERE prefix='M1';
```

My query matches one row so I am expecting the value of total_count to be 1.  However instead it is returning -1.  Does anyone know why if would be returning a negative value?

Comment: how are you reading the query results? Show your code ;-)

Comment: Have you tried contacting Fisher Price for support with your MyFirstRDBMS? Behavior like this is precisely why I avoid MySQL.

Comment: @JanDvorak I get the negative value when I run the query on the command line

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55659) bug report, you need to run `REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: Hard to believe that fixed it. You must have changed something else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar`? Or in more general terms, did you read the row count instead of the result [in the first column of the first row]?

That's what I did to get a `-1`. Oops.